# Front end for backend DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

We have a application landscape with many micro services and use a backend for front-end for the UI to aggregate data.

Would you put the aggregation logic (combine data from multiple micro services) in the domain or application layer of the Front End For Backend Application?

It feels like business logic, however, there is no persistance only data retrieval, so I am in doubt where to put it?

Comment: I smell over-engineering here. BFF architecture should be straightforward as, as you said, this is a layer responsible for data aggregation only. In my opinion, you shouldn't ask yourself those questions for a BFF.

Answer (score 0):

Backend-for-front-end implementations shouldn't need to contain any real business logic as they only serve as gateways which are focused on specific front-end clients (mobile, desktop, web, etc.).

So of course there is ***logic*** in your BFFs but it will rather be the **aggregation logic**. Taking care of processing the front-end client requests and managing the workflow to communicate with the involved microservices - be it via synchronous or asynchronous communication - as well as aggregating the data and serving it back to the client.

What you usually end up with are some kind of *controllers handling the API requests* (e.g. via REST), some *services containing the aggregation logic*, some kind of *anemic models* (i.e. without logic) representing the client requests and responses and stuff like that.

I don't know what technology stack you are on but you can have a look at some [sample BFF implementations](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/dev/src/ApiGateways) in a microservices architecture at the Microsoft powered eshopOnContainers project.

***Note***: if you are really sure there is business logic required in your BFF I guess you might have to consider if this should rather be part of an already existing microservice or if you even might not have discovered a new bounded context yet this logic rather fits in.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally Backend for frontend should not have any business logic. It should do authentication/authorization & routing logic.

If you are willing to do lots of aggregation and lots of frontends (need different set of data) then you may use GraphQL.